# React + Redux: Component does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Trying out React + Redux, and probably am doing something obviously stupid, because a component that fires an action to fetch data over the network does not get updated (re-rendered) when the data is fetched.

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

The top-level index.js serving as an entry point for the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger();

import routes from './routes';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxPromise, logger)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Top-level container App:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../actions';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Showcase from '../components/showcase';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    resources: state.resources
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchResources: () => {
      dispatch(Actions.fetchResources());
    }
  }
}


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log('props in App', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Showcase
          fetchResources={this.props.fetchResources}
          resources={this.props.resources}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

Component that triggers an action to sends a request for data when it is about to mount and is supposed to show the fetched data:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Showcase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchResources();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('resources', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        This is showcase
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({resources: state.resources}))(Showcase)
```

Action Creator:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchResources() {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_FIRST,
    payload: axios.get('/sampledata/1.json')
  }
}
```

Reducer for the fetch action:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export default function resourcesReducer (state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_FIRST:
      console.log('about to return', Object.assign (state, {resources: action.payload.data }))
      return Object.assign (state, {resources: action.payload.data });
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

and finally the root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import navigationReducer from './navigation-reducer';
import resourcesReducer from './resources-reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navigationReducer,
  resourcesReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

So, here is what I am observing. The action to request data is successfully triggered, a request is sent, the reducer receives it when the promise is resolved, and updates the state with the fetched data. At this point, I would expect the top-level `App` component and the `Showcase` component to detect that the store has updated, and to re-render, but I do not see it in the console.

Also, I am confused by `redux-logger`’s console output:

[image]

Specifically, I am surprized to see that the `state` contains reducers from the rootReducer — I don't know if it's right (an example on [Redux logger Github page](https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger) shows a state without reducers). It also seems surprising that the `prev state` as reported by `redux-logger` contains the same `resourcesReducer` object as the `next state`, although intuitively I would expect `prev state` to be more or less empty.

Could you please point out what I am doing wrong and how to get React components respond to the `state` changes?

==================================================

**UPDATED:**

1) Changed the `mapStateToProps` function in the `App` component so that it correctly maps to reducer states:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    resources: state.resourcesReducer
  }
}
```

2) Still passing the `resources` down to the `Showcase component:

```
  render() {
    console.log('props in App', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <Header navigateActions={this.props.navigateActions}/>
        React simple starter
        <Showcase
          fetchResources={this.props.fetchResources}
          resources={this.props.resources}
        />
      </div>
    );
```

3) Trying to display `resources` on the screen by stringifying it to see what’s actually inside this object:

```
  render() {
    console.log('resources', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        This is showcase {JSON.stringify(this.props.resources)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

See this on the screen: `This is showcase {}`. The component does not seem to re-render.

Here’s the screenshot of the console showing that App’s props have updated with the values from the `next state`. Still, that did not cause the component to re-render:

[image]

**UPDATED AGAIN:** And my javascript-fu was poor, too. I did not quite realize that by returning `Object.assign (state, {resources: action.payload.data });` I was in fact mutating the state, and that a simple inversion of arguments would let me achieve what I intended. Thanks to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140008/react-redux-store-updates-but-react-does-not) on SO for enlightenment.

Comment: did u try adding key to the root reducer object? `const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navigation: navigationReducer,
  resources: resourcesReducer
});`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am surprized to see that the state contains reducers from the rootReducer

This is how it works. Take a closer look at `combineReducers()`.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navigationReducer,
  resourcesReducer
});
```

Recognise that it's not a list of parameters; it's a single object parameter. Perhaps it is clearer in verbose syntax:

```
var rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navigationReducer: navigationReducer,
  resourcesReducer: resourcesReducer
});
```

The `resourcesReducer` key points to the state returned by the `resourcesReducer()` function. That is, the `state` variable within the `resourcesReducer()` is just one part of the entire state.

The functions passed to `connect()` take the entire state as an argument. What yours should actually look like is this:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  resources: state.resourcesReducer.resources
}))(Showcase);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made it clearer what the relationships between the state and the reducers (and combineReducers) are, but even after I updated my code (see the UPDATED section of my original question), an update of the state does not lead to a component’s rerendering. I now subscribe only my `App` component to the store, and have changed the `mapStateToProps` function to return `{resources: state.resourcesReducer}`. I see that the state updates and that `App`'s props reflect this change, but this does not cause the App (or the Showcase) to re-render. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what was happening. My `Object.assign` was wrong too. I was mutating the state: `return Object.assign (state, {resources: action.payload.data })` while what I really needed to do was to return a new object (e.g. `return Object.assign ({resources: action.payload.data }, state)`). Silly me. Seems to be a common mistake though; there is a very similar post on SO that I missed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140008/react-redux-store-updates-but-react-does-not