# connected react-redux component does not rerender upon state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to write a simple test react-redux app to begin working with the gmail API, and right now state changes are not forcing a re-render.

**What I have done**:

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678255/react-redux-component-does-not-rerender-on-store-state-change).  That person's problem seemed to be caused by not `connect`-ing the component, but as far as I know I am doing that.  I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000395/react-redux-component-does-not-update).  That person's problem was caused by misunderstanding how `combineReducers` set objects on state, but I don't *think* I have the same misunderstanding.  I'm sure I have some other one!

Here is my top level container, with routing:

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react'
import {Router, Route, IndexRedirect, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'

import store from './store'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import WhoAmI from './components/WhoAmI'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound'
import { handleClientLoad } from './gmailApi'

const ExampleApp = connect(
  ({ auth }) => ({ user: auth })
)(
  ({ user, children }) =>
    <div>
      <nav>
        {user ? <WhoAmI/> : <Login/>}
      </nav>
      {children}
    </div>
)

const onAppEnter = () => {
  handleClientLoad()
}

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={ExampleApp}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} onEnter={onAppEnter} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

Here is my code to render the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { handleAuthClick, handleSignOutClick } from '../gmailApi'
import store from '../store'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


var authorizeButton = <button id="authorize-button" onClick={() => { handleAuthClick() }}>Authorize</button>
var signOutButton = <button id="signout-button" onClick={handleSignOutClick}>Sign Out</button>


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    labels: state.gmail.labels,
    isSignedIn: state.gmail.isSignedIn
  }
}

export const Labels = ({ isSignedIn, labels }) => {
  var button = isSignedIn ? signOutButton : authorizeButton
  console.log("labels ", labels)
  return (
    <div>
      {button}
      <ul>
        {labels && labels.map(label => <li>{label}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {labels: [], isSignedIn: false}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Labels labels={this.props.labels} isSignedIn={this.props.isSignedIn}/>
    )
  }

}

connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

Here is my gmail reducer and action creators:

```
let initialState = {
    labels: [],
    isSignedIn: false
}

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
  switch (action.type) {
  case SIGNED_IN:
    newState.isSignedIn = action.isSignedIn
    return newState
  case RECEIVE_LABELS:
    newState.labels = action.labels
    return newState
  }

  return state
}

const SIGNED_IN = 'SIGNED_IN'
export const signedIn = isSignedIn => ({
  type: SIGNED_IN, isSignedIn
})


const RECEIVE_LABELS = 'LABELS'
export const receiveLabels = labels => ({
    type: RECEIVE_LABELS, labels
})


export default reducer
```

Here is where I combine reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: require('./auth').default, 
  gmail: require('./gmail').default
})
export default rootReducer
```

Here is a screenshot showing my console.  (I don't really understand this cross-frame origin error and would welcome an explanation, but I assume it's ancillary to my problem since I get past it and succeed in passing an action through the reducer.)  [image]

I succeed in console logging labels on the first render, but after labels is set on the state there is no rerender, and I don't console log labels again (or render the list of labels on the page).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

p.s. And, for completeness, here is where I'm doing async gmail api stuff.  (I know I am not following the format of async action creators right now.  I'm working with sample code from the gmail api and am just trying to get things up and running at first and then expand and clean up my code.  I don't think the problem can possibly be in here because state gets populated fine; I just can't rerender the page.)

```
import store from '../store'
import { signedIn, receiveLabels } from '../reducers/gmail'
import gapi from './gapi'
import '../store'

var CLIENT_ID = '<stack overflow doesn't need to know this>';

// Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify";


/**
 *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
 */


export const handleClientLoad = function() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

/**
 *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
 *  listeners.
 */
function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus)

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());


    });
}

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {

        console.log(isSignedIn)
        store.dispatch(signedIn(isSignedIn))
}

/**
 *  Sign in the user upon button click.
 */
export const handleAuthClick = function(event) {
    console.log("got here")
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    fetchLabels()
}

/**
 *  Sign out the user upon button click.
 */
export const handleSignoutClick = function(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

/**
 * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
 * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
 *
 * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
 */

/**
 * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
 * are found an appropriate message is printed.
 */
function fetchLabels() {
    console.log("gapi client ", gapi.client)
    gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
        'userId': 'me'
    }).then(function (response) {
        var labels = response.result.labels;
        store.dispatch(receiveLabels(labels))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error I see is that you aren't exporting the connected component.  You export the component, and then connect it later.  The connect function returns a new Higher Order Component; it doesn't affect the component itself.  Also, the connect function takes a second argument: the action creators that will dispatch the action to the state store.  You need to import those actions if you want them to fire off to your reducers.

You have:

```
export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {labels: [], isSignedIn: false}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Labels labels={this.props.labels} isSignedIn={this.props.isSignedIn}/>
    )
  }

}

connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

just change it to:

```
import * as actions from './nameOfActionsFolder';

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {labels: [], isSignedIn: false}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Labels labels={this.props.labels} isSignedIn={this.props.isSignedIn}/>
    )
  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

That way you will be exporting the connected component.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, and the only reason I haven't upvoted and accepted your answer yet is that now for some reason the connection to the gmail api is not working and I don't get the labels updated on state, so I can't verify that your suggestion fixes anything.  I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong, and whether it would be appropriate to update my question or ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not how how that api works.  Also, you wouldn't need local state if you are using redux.  Perhaps a good way to trouble shoot is to get rid of redux, and try to make it work with local state in the react component, and then factor out the functionality into redux.

Comment: I fixed it.  I just needed to call fetchLabels() as a .then off of .signIn().  I think the only reason that wasn't causing trouble earlier was that my signed in state was persisting in the browser so there was always a user for fetchLabels to find.  I'll accept your answer.  Thanks for your help!