# redux state updated, but doesn't trigger page change (re-render)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I have seen below artilces, but my problem is different

http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering

[React-redux store updates but React does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140008/react-redux-store-updates-but-react-does-not)

[My Redux state has changed, why doesn't React trigger a re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513753/my-redux-state-has-changed-why-doesnt-react-trigger-a-re-render)

Chrome redux extension shows there is a diff (so no re-render is not by state mutation):
[image]

But re-render not tigger.

---

I am using react-boilerplate as base, and I am using Immutable.js

### reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  tags: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name:'t1',
      hexcolor: '#ccc',
      shortcut: 'ctrl+1',
      desc :'desc'
    }
  ],
});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_TAGS_SUCCESSED:
      return state.set('tags', action.tags)
    case ADD_TAG_SUCCESSED:
      return state.update('tags', arr => arr.push(action.tag))
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

### Selectors

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const selectTagPage = (state) => state.get('tagPage');

export const makeSelectTags = () => createSelector(
  selectTagPage,
  (state) => state.get('tags') && state.get('tags').toJS()
);
```

### TagPage(Index.js)

```
export class TagPage extends React.PureComponent { 

  render() {
    const {tags, corpusId } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TagTable data={tags} {...this.props} ></TagTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  tags: makeSelectTags(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    requestTags: (corpusId) =>
    dispatch({ type:REQUEST_TAGS, corpusId }),
    updateTag: (id, new_tag) =>
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_TAG, id , new_tag }),
    addTag: (tag) =>
    dispatch({ type: ADD_TAG, tag }),
    deleteTag: (tag) =>
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_TAG, tag }),
  };
}

const ConnectedTagPage = allCompose('tagPage', saga, reducer, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TagPage)

ConnectedTagPage.defaultProps = {
  tags: [],
}

export default ConnectedTagPage;
```

### TagTable (TagPage's child)

```
class TagTable extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    const {classes, data, tagColormap, updateTag, addTag, deleteTag } = this.props;
    const trigger = <Button raised primary>新增</Button>

    return (
      <div>
        <TagSubmitDialog title={'TAG'} trigger={trigger} obj={null} handleSubmit={(tag) => addTag(tag)} ></TagSubmitDialog>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>名称</TableCell>
              <TableCell>色值</TableCell>
              <TableCell>快捷键</TableCell>
              <TableCell>备注</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data && data.map((n) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={n.id}>
                  <TableCell>
                    {n.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {n.hexcolor}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    { n.shortcut}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    { n.desc}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>

      </div>
    );

  }

}
```

No matter how state change, TagTable does't change.

[image]

### Debug detail:

select change too:
[image]

page also get new tags:
[image]

table get new tags:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out that because of `<TableRow key={n.id}>` .

I have a initial data with id `1`, and my test data id is `1` too. 
So it due to react not allow same key ...